# Recursive function does not return array in python

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a simple code that returns the path to the destination node in BST.

[image]

```py
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

root = TreeNode(6)
root.left = TreeNode(2)
root.right = TreeNode(8)
root.left.left = TreeNode(0)
root.left.right = TreeNode(4)
root.left.right.left = TreeNode(3)
root.left.right.right = TreeNode(5)
root.right.left = TreeNode(7)
root.right.right = TreeNode(9)
```

After defining the tree;

```py
p = 2
q = 8

def pathFind(path, cur, node): # path : path the function walked throug so far
                               # cur : current node
                               # node : destination node's value 
  
  #print(f'current node value is {cur.val}')
  #print(path)
  ## ending condition ##
  if cur.val == node: # If we reach the destination node
    return path
  
  elif cur.val < node and cur.right != None : 
    # 'if cur.right != None:' line is useless since the problem guarantees the existence of destination value in BST 
    path.append(cur)

    return pathFind(path, cur.right, node)
  elif cur.val > node and cur.left != None: # cur.val > node:
    path.append(cur)
    return pathFind(path, cur.left, node)
  else:
    return None

path_p = pathFind([root], root, p)
```

I checked that my function reaches the destination and record the path toward it without any problem, but the last line - path_p = pathFind([root], root, p) doesn't work.

Anyone could help?

Comment: You probably forgot the `return` keyword in the `elif` and `else` branches: `return pathFind(path, cur.right, node)` and `return pathFind(path, cur.left, node)`

Comment: @Jesper thanks for ur comment, but still the answer doesn't come out as I expected. For example, when p = 2, path contains [node with 6, node with 6], not a [node with 6, node with 2].

Comment: @JunyeongAhn You have to check for whether node's left or right value is None or not,  checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73099027/16177121)

Comment: @SidharthMudgil I intentionally deleted that condition in my code since the problem guarantees the target exists in BST which means there is no chance I go to empty node.

Comment: Even if it was the very problem, I think I should have no problem when I set the target as 2 because it does exist in BST which means I never go to empty node.

Comment: @JunyeongAhn what if you want to find a path for 16? it doesn't exist, for your case adding return keyword before each recursive call might work

Comment: @SidharthMudgil The problem guarantees the target 100% exist in BST. That's why I keep  testing with target (node in my code) = 2. I don't have to check with the case with target being 16. Moreover, My code does not work well for target = 2 even if I add return lines

Comment: I'll update my code. Would u please see it again?

Comment: Also I've just checked that there's no problem with my answer when I delete codes to figure out 'whether node's left or right value is None or not'

Comment: @JunyeongAhn your code is working

Answer (score 1):

In function `pathFind()`, the path is returned only by the execution where the tested node contains the target value.  The (all) previous executions discard that return value.  Fix it by putting `return` before the recursive calls.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, but still the result is not the same to my expectation as I commented above :(

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to find the path for a target node

```
def pathFind(path, node, target):
    if node == None:
        return
    else:
        path.append(node.val)
        if node.val == target:
            return path
        elif node.val < target and node.right != None:
            return pathFind(path, node.right, target)
        elif node.val > target and node.left != None:
            return pathFind(path, node.left, target)
        else:
            return None

print(pathFind([], root, 9))
```

**output**

```
[6, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Maaaan ur code works!! Would u let me know what the problem is in my code?

Comment: @JunyeongAhn You're not checking for whether the left/right value is None or not which leads to an infinite call and also you are not returning the function call.

Answer (score 0):

A few remaining issues (after the edits to your question):

- The root node is in most cases added *twice* to the path: once in the initial call, and again when moving to the left or right subtree of the root node: `cur` is the root node and `path.append(cur)` is executed.

  So, pass an empty list in the initial call instead of `[root]`
- When the target node is found, that node is not appended to the path, yet I suppose it should be the final node in the path. So `path.append(cur)` should also happen in the first `if` block.

Those changes will fix your code.